# Catch ColumnWidthChanged event except data source updated for DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

The data source of my `dataGridView` (grdBandControl) is updated every seconds.

Each time it is updated, `grdBandControl_ColumnWidthChanged` is fired.

I want to resize columns manually by resizing column header visually and store in a relevant variable.

How can I distinguish `grdBandControl_ColumnWidthChanged` is fired either:

- Datasource updated
- Resized visually

Codes are as below as it can give idea:

```
class ColumnNameWidth
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public int ColumnWidth { get; set; }
}
List<ColumnNameWidth> ColumnNameWidths = new List<ColumnNameWidth>();

void grdBandControl_DataSourceUpdate()
{
    //some dataTable from Db i.e.
    grdBandControl.DataSource = dataTable;
    foreach (var columnNameWidth in ColumnNameWidths)
    {
        grdBandControl.Columns[columnNameWidth.ColumnName].Width = columnNameWidth.ColumnWidth;
    }
}

private void grdBandControl_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in grdBandControl.Columns)
    {
        var columnNameWidth = ColumnNameWidths.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ColumnName == col.Name);
        if (columnNameWidth != null)
            columnNameWidth.ColumnWidth = col.Width;
        else
            ColumnNameWidths.Add(new ColumnNameWidth
            {
                ColumnName = col.Name,
                ColumnWidth = col.Width
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after digging some, I figure out using `grdBandControl_MouseUp` instead of `grdBandControl_ColumnWidthChanged` solves issue.

```
private void grdBandControl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in grdBandControl.Columns)
    {
        var columnNameWidth = ColumnNameWidths.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ColumnName == col.Name);
        if (columnNameWidth != null)
            columnNameWidth.ColumnWidth = col.Width;
        else
            ColumnNameWidths.Add(new ColumnNameWidth
            {
                ColumnName = col.Name,
                ColumnWidth = col.Width
            });
    }
}
```